# Applet lifecycle: what's the practical difference between init() & start(), and destroy() & stop()?

Tags: java, applet, lifecycle

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) and [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/appletMethods.html) have information about the four applet lifecycle methods (`init() -> start() -> stop() -> destroy()`).  But they talk mostly in abstract language.

What I'm looking for are concrete examples of when it makes a difference if I put my code in `init` vs `start`, and similarly for `destroy` vs `stop`.  The only thing I've found so far is in the tutorial's description of the `destroy` method.  It says:

> Note: Keep implementations of the
>   destroy method as short as possible,
>   because there is no guarantee that
>   this method will be completely
>   executed. The Java Virtual Machine
>   might exit before a long destroy
>   method has completed.

(I'm a bit shocked that the above isn't in the javadoc.)

**Edit:** to be more specific: Can anyone provide a browser + JVM combo that, upon some specific action (switching tabs, hitting the 'back' button, etc.), invokes `stop` but not `destroy` (or `start` but not `init`)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`init` and `destroy` are called when the applet is loaded or unloaded, respectively.  It's possible for a browser to load an applet and stop it, but not destroy it, when navigating around, switching tabs, etc.

`start` and `stop` are for pausing and resuming the applet, in the case above (when the applet  becomes, or ceases to be, shown on a page).

I don't know if any browser actually does keep an applet loaded, so it may not matter much.  But as far as i learned it, the general rule is:

- `init` should get the applet ready to run, but not actually set it in motion.  The applet should be in a "stopped" state upon return from `init`.  (A stopped applet should be using as few resources as practically possible, and no CPU.)
- `start` should start the applet running (starting threads, etc).  It generally won't read params and reload images and all that, as that should be done in `init`.
- `stop` should undo what `start` does...returning the applet to the "stopped" state, but leaving it able to `start` again.  It should not undo any of `init`'s work, as that would leave the applet unstartable if the functionality is properly separated.
- `destroy` should do any final cleanup before the applet is unloaded.  It basically undoes `init`.  It should not stop the applet; that's `stop`'s job, and should already be done before `destroy` is called.

Comment: I did some experiments in IE, firefox, and safari, and wasn't able to find a case where stop was called without also calling destroy.  So you're "it may not matter much" comment seems to be right on.

Answer (score 1):

In practical terms, I think that `start()` and `stop()` were intended to be called each time an applet-bearing page was viewed (for example, using the browser's "back" and "forward" buttons), while `init()` and `destroy()` were only called once.

It's been about 15 years since I wrote an applet though, so I might be mis-remembering.