# adding keylistener returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, keyevent

I am learning to program 2d games in java for quite a while. In my lastest game I have tried to create a private class that will handle the key events from within the Player class, I did it like this:

```
package game;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Player {

    final private int MOVEMENTSPEED = 4;
    final private int BOOST = 8;
    final private EventHandler HANDLER = new EventHandler();

    private int x, y;
    private int speedX, speedY;

    public Player(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void update(){
        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;
    }

    public int getSpeedX() {
        return speedX;
    }

    public int getSpeedY() {
        return speedY;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public EventHandler getHandler(){
        return HANDLER;
    }

    private class EventHandler implements KeyListener{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_W: speedY = -MOVEMENTSPEED;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S: speedY = MOVEMENTSPEED;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A: speedX = -MOVEMENTSPEED;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D: speedX = MOVEMENTSPEED;
                break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_W: speedY = 0;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S: 
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A: speedX = 0;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D: 
                break;
            }   
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

and here is where i try to add the eventHandler class to the class that deals with the game loop, painting and such:

```
public class FrameWork extends Applet implements Runnable {

private URL base;
private Graphics second;

private Image image;

public static Player p;


@Override
public void start() {
    p = new Player(400, 400);
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void init() {
    setSize(1000, 600);
    setFocusable(true);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("Assassin");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    **this.addKeyListener(p.getHandler());**
}
```

I have already worked with keylistener but did it either without the an extra class (implementing the methods within the same class of the game loop) or by creating a completely differnent class and using its instance.

Anyway I tried to do it differently because it seemed more comfortable but it always returns the error java.lang.NullPointerException and I don't understand why.

Thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifecycle of an `Applet` starts with `init` and later `start` is called.
You initialize the player in `start` which is called after `init`, therefore `p` in `init` is null.

Create the player in the `init` method.

See [Applet lifecycle: what's the practical difference between init() & start(), and destroy() & stop()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661679/applet-lifecycle-whats-the-practical-difference-between-init-start-and)

Comment: `p` shouldn't be created in the `init` method, since it is static (although that is probably wrong anyway).

Comment: In that case the registering of the key listener could be moved into the `start` method after `Player` creation and before the thread is started.

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes:

Make your Player variable non-static.

Initialize this variable in the `init()` method rather than the `start()` method.

```
public Player p; //changed this to be an instance variable (non-static)


@Override
public void start() {     
                //moved initialization of player to init() method
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void init() {
    setSize(1000, 600);
    setFocusable(true);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("Assassin");
    frame.setResizable(false);

    p = new Player(400, 400); //initialize Player here
    this.addKeyListener(p.getHandler());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. I learned how to use applet from some guide in which the variables were created within start() (I guess because it did not matter much there).

Comment: @user3917631 Glad it worked. If you want to can accept this answer by clicking the green tick to the left. I'll get some points and you'll get some points as well :)